# One class per file in R

Tags: r, oop

R beginner with a two part question -

1. I like the one class per file 'rule' in 'other' languages - is this a common practise in R also ?
2. How would I go about doing this in R ? From the documentation I've read so far, I would have to create a package and use 'require'. However, will I need to write man pages and documentation for each package ? (One file may contain a very small class that I don't really want to document). Are there any alternative ways of doing this ?

Many thanks

Comment: Rules are made to be broken. If it suits you to have very small code files, then do that. If it's too cumbersome, do something else. Writing documentation is good practise, whether you are writing a package or not. So, I've written some truisms. What works for you is going to depend on your situation. You've give too little information to work with. At the moment it's not a real question. Please consider adding some more detail and try to be more specific on what exactly your question is.

Comment: OK, for simplicity - I have multiple classes in one file and I would like to separate them into individual files. What would be the best way to do this ?

Comment: Please edit your question with this information / request, so that the question is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options for you:

1. ProjectTemplate may have functionality that would let you load all source scripts in a given directory automatically.
2. You can write a simple script that does it yourself by `source()`ing  the output of `dir()`.  `taRifx::readdir` does something similar to load all data files in a directory.
3. Likely the best answer: put all your functions into a package, even if you don't release it to CRAN.  All .R files in the R directory automatically become part of the package when you build it.  Bonus: documentation becomes easier as well (use `roxygen2`).